# Configuring ant to use the Apache XML resolver

Tags: xml, ant

I've been trying to get ant (9.6 and 9.7) to resolve XML URI lookups using the apache xml resolver. I've clearly made some sort of error that I'm overlooking. I'd be grateful if anyone could see what I've configured incorrectly here.

ant does not appear to use the resolver under any circumstances. What have I misconfigured?

I have the following:

**build.xml**

```
<project basedir="." name="testme">

  <xslt
    style="input.xsl"
    in="input.xml"
    out="output.xml">


    <xmlcatalog>
      <catalogpath>
        <pathelement 
        location="${basedir}${file.separator}catalog.xml"/>
      </catalogpath>
    </xmlcatalog>        
  </xslt>  
</project>
```

**catalog.xml**

```
<catalog xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:entity:xmlns:xml:catalog"   
  prefer="public">
  <uri name="input.xsl" uri="test-input.xsl"/>
  <uri name="input.xml" uri="test-input.xml"/>    
</catalog>
```

The current directory does contain both test-input.xsl and test-input.xml.
I've got a `.antrc` file in my home directory which contains just the line:

`ANT_OPTS=-Dxml.catalog.verbosity=99`

`resolver.jar` is in the `.ant/lib` subdirectory of my home directory. I've also tried placing it in ant's own lib directory.

Running ant I can see that the verbosity property is set so any activity using the catalog should be dumped to standard error. Running `ant -debug` suggests that it's not trying to use the resolver at all (no sign of it in the stack trace). The build fails with a message that `.../input.xml does not exist`.

What have I done wrong (and/or misunderstood)?

Answer (score 0):

Answering this myself for future reference. The resolver is only used *within* the xml validation and xslt tasks. So…

```
<xslt
    style="input.xsl"
    in="input.xml"
    out="output.xml">
…
</xslt>
```

would lead to the resolver being used for any `xsl:import` or `xsl:include` statements in `input.xsl` but ant will not use the resolver to locate documents referenced in either the `style` or the `in` attributes.